# php selenium waitForElementAbsent method

Tags: selenium, phpunit

IN phpunit / selenium testing application of mine, there is a requirement to wait for further execution till the a element disappears.

There is a function to check waitForElementPresent, wanted help in framing similar function logic but checking element absence.

Comment: Are you working with Selenium or Selenium2 ?

Comment: How did you found that out? Are you using the SeleniumIDE browser plugin?

Comment: yes, a package of it. '.jar' file